# I am trying to combine this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, passwords, show-hide, password-protection

So, I am trying to password protect a button that shows some text on my website.
Here is the code for the password protect script I have.

```
<SCRIPT>
  function passWord() {
    var testV = 1;
    var pass1 = prompt('Enter The Code On Your Card Here.',' ');
    while (testV < 3) {
      if (!pass1)
        history.go(-1);
      if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "abc123") {
        window.open('card1e.html');
        break;
      }
      testV+=1;
      var pass1 =
      prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.','Password');
    }
    if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3)
      history.go(-1);
    return " ";
  }
</SCRIPT>
<CENTER>
  <FORM>
    <input type="button" value="Have This Card? Click Here!" onClick="passWord()">
  </FORM>
</CENTER>
```

The show/hide script I am using is this:

```
<script>
  <a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))">Click here</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function hideshow(which){
    if (!document.getElementById)
      return
    if (which.style.display=="block")
      which.style.display="none"
    else
      which.style.display="block"
  }
</script>

<div id="adiv" style="font:24px bold; display: block">Now you see me</div>
```

Is can't figure out how to get it so that when the password is entered correctly, it shows the button where you can show/hide some text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT>

    // Show Div if its hidden
    function showdiv(){

        // get the div   
        which = document.getElementById('adiv');

        // show hide
        if (!which)
            return
        else if (which.style.visibility=="hidden")
            which.style.visibility="visible";

    }

    // Test User Credentials
    function passWord(){

        var testV = 1;      
        var pass1 = prompt('Enter The Code On Your Card Here.');        // no need to give a space here
        while (testV < 3) {
            if (!pass1)
                history.go(-1);
            if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "abc123") {
                showdiv()  
                alert("Redirecting in 3 secs...")
                window.setTimeout(redirect,3000);       //wait for 3 secs then redirect to card1.html                       
                break;
            }
            testV+=1;
            var pass1 = prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.',"password");
        }
        if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3)
        history.go(-1);
        return " ";
    }

    function redirect(){

        window.open('card1e.html');

    }

</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<div id="adiv" style="font:24px bold; visibility:hidden">Now you see me</div>
<CENTER>
<input type="button" value="Click to enter credentials toe see the text block" onClick="passWord()">  
</CENTER>
</body>
```

Comment: Changes to your code:
1. what you were doing using `block` I did with the `visibility`
2. Merged the Code as you required
3. Added a JS Time out function as I was not sure what you wanted to do in your code. This will give the end user 3 seconds to read the text before redirecting to `card1.html` probably just have the text on `card1.html`? your the best judge

Comment: Thank you so much! I had been trying to figure this out for hours, and now I am finally able to do it. Thank you!